# What does $_POST actually return?

Tags: php, http, post

Just a quick question. I am doing a small project with php and have now come at a point where I need to know what does the method $_POST in php actually return? Is it an array or some key/value pairs or what exactly? I am unable to the find exact information about the same. Please help me in understanding this stuff. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [the manual may help](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) (and it's _not_ a method, it's a variable).

Comment: Read the documentation, please! http://www.php.net/manual/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` / `var_dump($_POST)`, dude.

Comment: `array( html_name => html_value )` from `<input name="html_name" value="html_value">`

Comment: Ok the method is "post" and variable is "$_POST". Thanks for the clarification @Wrikken.

Comment: @ComFreek: I had checked that page before posting the question. All I was looking for something like ceejayoz has commented. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Yes, it is an array. Try the [Official documentation](http://php.net/superglobals)

Answer (score 2):

It's an associative array containing content that was sent from a html form using the post method.

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php):

> An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method.